# StackBlitz ngcc failed to run on my npm library with Ivy enabled

Tags: angular, angular-library, stackblitz

I have published an Angular 10 library to npm and it works fine in a local Angular 10 project with Ivy enabled but if I try and use it on StackBlitz I have to disable Ivy.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tapxx5?file=tsconfig.json

but working with Ivy disabled

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vbpzem?file=tsconfig.json

Not sure why I would have to turn Ivy off for StackBlitz but I can use it fine in a local CLI Ivy project.

Comment: Facing the same issue as we speak. Got a clue for you: My library (lib1) depends on another library of mine (lib2) which depended on lodash. StackBlitz was failing for both lib1 and lib2. I removed the dependency on lodash and created my own simplified functions. Now lib2 works but StackBlitz still complains about lib1.

Please post updates here. 

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work by going to the settings on the left panel and disabling `Enable Ivy` then doing a hard refresh on the browser.

Comment: But this is unhelpful for people who want to use my library in a StackBlitz, I feel it makes the library look bad when it doesn't work with Ivy.

Comment: Yes, but StackBlitz is not being used to build apps, its being used to quickly test and share code. You then will most likely take that code into a real repository and build and send it to your real environments from there. During those builds Evy can be turned on.

Answer (score 1):

This is apparently a recent recurring issue which has been [filed on their GitHub repo](https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/1364).
Similar cases are rising, working with Ivy off.

I think it is safe to assume the problem is from their part, as long as packages are running fine on regular environments.

https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/1364

**Edit**: as [Ahmed pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386983/stackblitz-ngcc-failed-to-run-on-my-npm-library-with-ivy-enabled#comment118658961_67126359), confirmed by the StackBlitz team on Twitter

Comment: It is from their side in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/stackblitz/status/1380501561311330309), They acknowledged it here and actually suggested your solution to turn Ivy off

Comment: @AhmedMohamedeen the question states it works with Ivy off. But it makes my library look bad if importing it crashes a StackBlitz.

Comment: @AdrianBrand i think Simon have answer to your original question. Please consider validate it