# How to get Microsoft MSAL angular12-sample-app working in StackBlitz?

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, stackblitz

I have a question that I want to ask help for regarding an Angular app that offers both B2B and B2C authentication flows.  I want it to be based off the Microsoft MSAL Angular exemplar project that uses HTTP_INTERCEPTORS and I want to have a StackBlitz example to illustrate clearly what I'm trying to achieve.

But I can't seem to get the project to work and wondering if someone with experience setting up a working angular project into StackBlitz can see what I'm doing wrong please.

The StackBlitz project is:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1yda6?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Any and all assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386983/stackblitz-ngcc-failed-to-run-on-my-npm-library-with-ivy-enabled - it seems that stackblitz sometimes have issues with Ivy (confirmed by the stackblitz devs). Try turning off Ivy in compiler options in tsconfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was with stackblitz having issues with Ivy. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63386983/stackblitz-ngcc-failed-to-run-on-my-npm-library-with-ivy-enabled).

I've forked your stackblitz and:

1. Added file extension the the app-routing.module (it was missing .ts extension).
2. Disabled Ivy in compiler options in the tsconfig.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mek7p9

Not sure if it works correctly (nor how it should work), but it does compile without throwing the errors, so that should take you in the right direction.